# Direct Drive Washer is going into spin cycle and then into neutrAl drain

Tags: drain, washing-machine, oil

I have a 30 year old Kitchen Aid Direct Drive Washer.  I recently replaced the Neutral Drain Pack.  I also replaced the oil with 80w- 90 gear oil.  All functions work well except the machine goes right into spin while draining instead of neutral drain. I then stops and when it should be going into spin, goes into neutral drain.  I turn it off and on and I’m back in spin cycle.  Why would these to be reversed?  Is it the oil viscosity possibly not allowing the latch to swing properly?

Comment: What oil are you suppose to use?  Were all connections done right?  Google might find a service manual for it, if you add the model number in your search.  Local appliance service store might have it also.

Comment: Did you, perhaps, install a part backwards? If there's any mechanical switching involved, one part upside down or backwards could cause something to run out of order.